# How do I make things go into a dropper using water?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a stream of water and a dropper next to it. I drop an item into the water and it travels to the dropper but doesn't go into it. How do I do this? How do I make it so that the item travels along the stream of water and then goes into the dropper without me having to do it manually?

Answer (score 7):

You need to make the water flow above a [Hopper](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hopper), pointing the Hopper to the Dropper.

You can then make a [Redstone Clock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_2_lA04cBg), a redstone system that activates the Dopper when it has items, or a button/lever to make the Dropper drop the items.

Comment: Giving a hopper a redstone signal disables it, rather than enabling it.

Comment: @AngusAtkinson Typo, activates the dropper, not hopper. When i mean activate, it's the same as sending a signal and making the dropper drop 1 item.